# wandb.Table raises error: AssertionError: columns argument expects a `list` object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, wandb

I'm very beginner with wandb , so this is very basic question.
I have dataframe which has my x features and y values.
I'm tryin to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.wandb.ai/examples)  to train model from my pandas dataframe . However, when I try to create wandb table from my pandas dataframe, I get an error:

```
wandb.init(project='my-xgb', config={'lr': 0.01})

#the log didn't work  so I haven't run it at the moment (the log 'loss') 
#wandb.log({'loss': loss, ...})


# Create a W&B Table with your pandas dataframe
table = wandb.Table(df1)
```

> AssertionError: columns argument expects a `list` object

I have no idea why is this happen, and why it excpect a list. In the tutorial it doesn't look like the dataframe is list.

My end goal - to be able to create wandb table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: `table = wandb.Table(dataframe=my_df)`.

The explanation of your specific case is at the bottom.

---

**Minimal example** of using `wandb.Table` with a DataFrame:

```py
import wandb
import pandas as pd

iris_path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv'
iris = pd.read_csv(iris_path)
table = wandb.Table(dataframe=iris)
wandb.log({'dataframe_in_table': table})
```

(Here the dataset is called the Iris dataset that consists of "3 different types of irises’ (Setosa, Versicolour, and Virginica) petal and sepal length, stored in a 150x4 numpy.ndarray")

There are two ways of creating W&B `Table`s according to [the official documentation](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/data-vis/log-tables#create-tables):

- **List of Rows**: Log named columns and rows of data. For example: `wandb.Table(columns=["a", "b", "c"], data=[["1a", "1b", "1c"], ["2a", "2b", "2c"]])` generates a table with two rows and three columns.
- **Pandas DataFrame**: Log a DataFrame using `wandb.Table(dataframe=my_df)`. Column names will be extracted from the DataFrame.

---

**Explanation**: Why `table = wandb.Table(my_df)` gives error "columns argument expects a `list` object"? Because `wandb.Table`'s init function looks like this:

```py
def __init__(
        self,
        columns=None,
        data=None,
        rows=None,
        dataframe=None,
        dtype=None,
        optional=True,
        allow_mixed_types=False,
    ):
```

If one passes a DataFrame without telling it's a DataFrame, `wandb.Table` will assume the argument is `columns`.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer! so, if I want to use my train-test sets, should I convert each one into dataframe? or there is  wandb function that is not scikit-learn split test train?

Comment: Hi @Reut, I am really sorry I don't think I fully understood your comment. I would say W&B is only used for visualisation/logging, and I would never use it for manipulating the data for training. Here is a super detailed [Guide to W&B Tables](https://wandb.ai/stacey/mnist-viz/reports/Guide-to-W-B-Tables--Vmlldzo2NTAzOTk#1.-how-to-log-a-wandb.table). Hope it helps!